# Problem running PHP code in Zend Studio

Tags: configuration, zend-studio, application-settings, zend-server-ce

I installed Zend Studio 8.0 and ZendServer-php-5.3.5-5.1.0-Windows_x86.exe.
But I am having problem running a PHP code.
I tried to run the default template DebugDemo.php.
It loads the url
*http://localhost/ExampleProject/DebugDemo.php*  **and shows the error:**
**404 Not Found.
The requested URL /ExampleProject/DebugDemo.php was not found on this server.**
I clicked on the icon (Open Zend Server Event list in Browser)
It opens up a web page where at the bottom it states:
**The license key is not set. Zend Server will run as Community Edition until a valid license is entered**
[image: Error]

**Have I missed something or gone wrong in configuring zend studio??**

Comment: Does ExampleProject/DebugDemo.php exist under the web server root?

Comment: I am new to Zend Studio. So I dont know the term 'web server root'. The file exists in the default workspace  *C:\Users\Kunal\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace7\ExampleProject\DebugDemo.php*   I went through the preferences and the server configurations but couldnt find what may be possibly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document root is set in the Apache configuration file httpd.conf.  It is probably in c:\program files\Zend\Apache\conf\httpd.conf.  You will need to change it to C:\Users\Kunal\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace7.

The license you will need to add under Administration -> License.  If you are a ZCE you should have gotten a free one.  If you simply downloaded the trial you will need to get a trial license.  I believe the link to do that is also on the license page.